# SQL: a set of results inside each result

Tags: mysql

I have a table `articles`, and it has a structure like this:

```
id, name, date, contents
```

And I have a table `authors`, and it has a structure like this:

```
id, article_id, name, email
```

A single article can have many authors.

How can I get a list of articles, with each row showing the multiple authors for that article (almost like a set of results inside each article row)

I feel like this is a simple thing to do with SQL, but I don't know the correct terms to look for.  I have been searching around all afternoon with to no avail.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you are asking about [GROUP_CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: You wouldn't normally store an article id in a table of authors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT articles.id, articles.name, GROUP_CONCAT(authors.name) AS authors
FROM articles LEFT JOIN authors ON articles.id = authors.article_id
GROUP BY articles.id, articles.name
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3569170284ebbbfa3544fc5c2c58ec2e)

Comment: This is great - but how do I also include articles that have no authors listed in this?  I have tried `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` but it didn't work?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` (see demo) have to work. You are using a additional condition (`WHERE`)?